# Why is this trial wave function a good choice to use with the variational principle?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, wavefunction, potential, variational-principle

I am learning about the variational principle and I want to understand how to pick "good" trial functions.

For example:

$$V(x) = \infty, x<0$$
$$V(x) = x, x \geq 0$$

and

$$\psi (x) = 2\sqrt{\lambda^3}xe^{-\lambda x}$$

My guess would be that this is a good trial function because the wave function goes to zero at infinity.

Comment: You're right that it going to zero as $x\to\infty$ is desirable. And what happens when $x\to 0$?

Comment: @lemon I ignored that area because the potential already goes to infinity at $x=0$, so *any* wavefunction will be zero there and thus the only area of interest is when $x \to \infty$. Would you agree with this?

Comment: Not an answer just a comment. I could not type the comment in the add comment section. I don't see any physically motivated reason, other than the decay condition, while guessing the trial wave function. Is it sufficient condition? Could you please tell condition on $\lambda$?

Comment: I believe the only condition on $\lambda$ is that it is real-valued (and of course it is the *adjustable* parameter here).

Comment: $\lambda$ is a parameter to be varied in order to get an upper bound on the energy of the ground state.

Comment: This seems like one of the most simple choices you could make - And it makes sense. The function has to go to zero at infinity and at zero, and the factors are there for normalization probably. (I didn't calculate, but it seems so)

Comment: @Omry ok that's what I was thinking. Thanks for confirming.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically any function would be a good initial choice provided:

- It satisfies boundary conditions
- It is normalizable
- It has some parameters to adjust

For particular cases like ground state of a 1D particle you also want it to have the same sign everywhere (since zeros are necessarily indication of excited states being included). The function you show does satisfy this.

Also, to improve precision you want it to be as close as practical to asymptotic solution at infinity. Your function is at least better than the one with e.g. decay at infinity $\sim x^{-n}$: true solution's asymptotics is indeed closer to exponential than to a power law.

Comment: To your comment about zeros and sign of $\psi (x)$: does that mean that my trial wavefunction should never include excited states? Wait, what does that even mean then?

Comment: @loltospoon this just means that generally you want to minimize influence of excited states on your estimate of ground state energy. But if your trial function has zeros, it already is guaranteed to include some excited states in a quantity you could have avoided by choosing the function without zeros. This is just usage of _a priori_ knowledge of the basic properties of ground state wavefunction.

Comment: The true solution's asymptotics are indeed closer to exponential than a power, but they're definitely not exponential in full. A much better ansatz would be to take the actual asymptotic solution, $\psi \sim \exp(-\frac23 x^{3/2})$, instead of a plain exponential.